# can I combine these 2 simple queries into one query?

Tags: sql, mysql

`select count(distinct id) from svn where name='ant' and type='Bug'`

and

`select count(distinct id) from svn where name='ant' and type='Feature'`

Is it possible to combine them into a single query that might **reduce the execution time** compared to running them individually?

Thanks for answering.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can use group by:

```
SELECT type, count(distinct id) AS cnt
FROM svn
WHERE name = 'ant'
AND type IN ('Feature', 'Bug')
GROUP BY type
```

Comment: Bang ON!! Gosh, I can't believe I didn't think of that. I guess sometimes you are just trying to think on a much higher level when the solution is actually very easy. Thanks a lot though.